# How to combine sub-reducer without creating separate entry in state in redux

Tags: redux

my question may sound a bit dumb, I'm still learning react and redux. 
I have `user` in my app and this is schema of my user state:

```
user : {
  error,
  isAuthed,
  authToken,
  isFetching,
  currentRole,
  roles : ['role', 'role'],
  paymentsInfo: [{invoice}, {invoice}, {invoice}]
}
```

Here is my my reducer for user:

```
function user(state = initialUserState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCHING_USER': {
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching : true
        }
    }
    case 'FETCHING_USER_ERROR': {
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching : false,
            error      : action.error
        }
    }
    case 'FETCHING_USER_SUCCESS': {
        return {
            // update user state
        }
    }
    // payments reducer
    case 'FETCH_PAYMENT_DETAILS': {
        return {
            ...state,
            payments : payments(state.payments, action)
        }
    }
    case 'FETCH_PAYMENT_SUCCESS': {
        return {
            ...state,
            payments : payments(state.payments, action)
        }
    }
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

I am maintaining payments reducer in different file and last 3 cases in `user` reducer matches to action of  `payments` reducer:

```
function payments(state = initialPaymentState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_PAYMENT_DETAILS' : {
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching : true
        }
    }
    case 'FETCH_PAYMENT_ERROR' : {
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching : false,
            error      : action.error
        }
    }
    case 'FETCH_PAYMENT_SUCCESS' : {
        return {
            ...state,
            isFetching : false,
            error      : '',
            invoices   : action.paymentDetails
        }
    }

    default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

I am not maintaining separate state for `payments`, but when I get payments data from API I need to update that in `user` state. Now my question is that is there a way to combine `user` and `payments` reducers together without creating separate state for `payments`

Comment: What do you mean - combine them together?

Comment: @Radio- by combine I meant that I don't want to write `payments` method's cases in `user` reducer and at the same time I want both of them in separate files and `payments` should not create new instance in main state tree is should be part of `user`(see the schema)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to update the state is to dispatch an action. So you should dispatch an action after you retrieve payment and modify user reducer to handle this action.
Also should be able to catch any action in your user reducer. If you do not need payments state you handle all actions in user reducer. If you would like to combine parts of your state check out combineReducers function from **redux**

Answer (score 0):

Your default case for user could return { ...state, payments : payments(state.payments, action) }

However, this looks like an anti-pattern for redux, and I think you should consider why you want to remove the case statements from user. Having them there makes it evident to people reading the code that those actions can affect the user state.